# Cannot run $http in AngularJS plunker

Tags: angularjs

I cannot run $http on the plunker. Could you help me check my code.

```
var QuizApp = angular.module('QuizApp', []);

QuizApp.controller('QuizController', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {

  $scope.message = "hey y'all";

  $http.get('questions.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.questions=data
  });

}]);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/sJHwt51k4RPKmq5eT2JF?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

you need to use .then instead of .success as it was deprecated with the angularjs version above **`1.3`**. You should also use .data to access the actual json response

```
QuizApp.controller('QuizController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.message = "hey y'all";
  $http.get('questions.json').then(function(data) {
    $scope.questions = data.data;
  });
}]);
```

**[PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/sJHwt51k4RPKmq5eT2JF?p=preview)**